# Savon request with elements that don't belong to a namespace

Tags: savon

I am using Savon 2.11.1 as a Ruby SOAP client. I create client with the following code:

```
client = Savon.client(
    :wsdl => "#{wsdl_file}",
    env_namespace: :soapenv, # changes env namespace to soapenv namespace in requests
    :logger => Rails.logger,
    :convert_request_keys_to => :none,
    :convert_response_tags_to => :none,
    :log_level => :debug,
    :pretty_print_xml => true,
    :namespaces => {
        "xmlns:tns" => "http://file.provisioning.services.com/",
        "xmlns:ns1" => "http://schemas.services.com/types/"}
)
```

I am trying to send a request where some of the elements have no namespace. The request should look as follows:

```
<tns:addFile>
    <mimeType>audio/wav</mimeType>   
    <ns1:data>ejrhkwerhjk4h5jk4h6j34htkwejfhks</ns1:data>
</tns:addFile>
```

Using the following code generates a request where the mimeType element belongs to namespace tns which is not accepted by the server.

```
body = {"mimeType" => "audio/wav", "ns1:data" => "ejrhkwerhjk4h5jk4h6j34htkwejfhks"}
soap_response = client.call(:add_file, :message => body)
```

Any ideas how I can send the mimeType without any namespace with Savon?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved this eventually by rewriting my Savon client. Rather than using a wsdl global, I now use namespace and endpoint globals as follows:

```
@client = Savon.client(
    :endpoint => "#{endPoint}",
    :namespace => "http://file.provisioning.services.com/",
    env_namespace: :soapenv, # changes env namespace to soapenv namespace in requests
    :logger => Rails.logger,
    :convert_request_keys_to => :none,
    :convert_response_tags_to => :none,
    :log_level => :debug,
    :pretty_print_xml => true,
    :namespaces => {
    "xmlns:ns1" => "http://schemas.services.com/types/"}
)
```

Using the following code now generates a request where the mimeType element does NOT belong to a namespace. Difference from before is the need to specify a soap action for each request (you can find the action name in your wsdl).

```
body = {"mimeType" => "audio/wav", "ns1:data" => "ejrhkwerhjk4h5jk4h6j34htkwejfhks"}
soap_response = client.call(:addFile, :message => body, :soap_action => "#{soapAction}"))
```